# PHP cURL Basic Authentication Alternatives for CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER & CURLOPT_USERPWD...?

Tags: php, authentication, curl, authorization, basic-authentication

Are there any alternatives to using CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER & CURLOPT_USERPWD for supplying Basic Authentication for cURL PHP?

I have a super long password, so CURLOPT_USERPWD wont work as it truncates at 256 characters.

```
curl_setopt($data, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
```

And I would like to stay away from using CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER for security reasons.

```
curl_setopt($data, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode($username . ":" . $password));
```

Any alternatives?

Comment: you could typically append it to your URL as parameters, although you would need to enforce HTTPS instead of HTTP

Answer (score 13):

What makes you think `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` is disabled for security reasons?

It accepts an array rather than a string.  Try this instead:

```
curl_setopt($data, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
            array(
              "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode($username . ":" . $password)
));
```

Comment: I don't see any security problem with using that option, why exactly do you want to avoid it?  The end result is exactly the same.

Comment: I wish I could use it, but ultimately it has bee disabled in our curl implementation.

Comment: Seems like an uninformed decision by whoever disabled it.  They allow you to make HTTP requests but then don't allow you to add your own headers?  I'd switch hosts if it was a hosting thing or if someone at your work did it ask them why and request it be enabled.  I think you're stuck otherwise.