# trouble connecting to Reed api - php

Tags: php, api, curl

I cant seem to connect to the reed api, docs here: https://www.reed.co.uk/developers/jobseeker

it states that:

```
You will need to include your api key for all requests in a basic authentication http header as the username, leaving the password empty.
```

my code currently looks like this:

```
    $api_key = 'MY-API-KEY';
    $url = ' https://www.reed.co.uk/api/1.0/search?keywords=Accounts Assistant&resultsToTake=100&resultsToSkip=0'
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, urlencode($url));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Authorization: Basic '.$api_key
    ));

    $server_output = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    var_dump($server_output);
```

the output is always:

```
bool(false)
```

Is there something I have missed? Is anyone else able to connect?
I've tried the url directly in my browser and it works, after using my api key in the popup auth box so I know the url and api key is correct.

Comment: Is your connection correct?

Comment: sorry, what do you mean by this?

Comment: Your authorization header should probably be `"Authorization: Basic ".base64_encode($your_api_key.":")`.

Comment: false means a failure to connect.

Comment: Did you get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Please see this answer ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/13654911/5056954 )

I tried to access the reed website and it seems its also asking for a username. Basic auth is also base64 encoded, so the following snippet should work for you if the username is not required:

```php
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Authorization: Basic '. base64_encode($api_key)
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use Postman. Once you tune up your query it gives you snippets of codes in many programming languages.

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "http://www.reed.co.uk/api/1.0/search?keywords=accountant&location=london",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
"authorization: Basic YOUR-AUTOMATICALLY-ENCODED-API-KEY-BY-POSTMAN",
"cache-control: no-cache"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

The code from Postman includes (, "postman-token: xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xx-xx"). Just delete that.

Answer (score 0):

It's the space in the URL parameter.

It should be:

```
$url = 'https://www.reed.co.uk/api/1.0/search?keywords=Accounts%20Assistant&resultsToTake=100&resultsToSkip=0'
```

Comment: Have you tested your solution before removing the space and after?

Comment: Yes, tested both ways and it was the space causing the error for me. As soon as I removed the space, the API is working nicely. I now make sure to urlencode the keyword string first.