# Authorization header is not passing in php curl is use CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl

I have come around a strange issue that when I am passing authorization header like below,

```
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                "Authorization: Basic XXXXXXXXXX",
                "Content-Type: application/json",
            ),
```

If I send like this then Authorization is not showing in request header.
But If I have Auth details like below,

```
CURLOPT_USERPWD=>"xxxxx:xxxxxx",
```

it will adding required Authorization header as I needed in htpp request.

So what is the issue in this? why it is not simply work as given in first code snippet? Also I am not able to send custom header, custom headers are also not available in request body.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13654892/php-curl-basic-authentication-alternatives-for-curlopt-httpheader-curlopt-user help?

Comment: ok so do you mean CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER is disabled on my curl implementation? do you know how I can check that on ubuntu server?